# python documentation using sphinx

Tags: python

I am using sphinx to create document for the python project, I have google type docstring with following settings:

```
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
    "sphinx_autodoc_typehints",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
]
```

```
napoleon_use_rtype = False
```

If set to true, in output I get `Return type: tuple[bool, str]` twice (in bold) and setting to false displays once (in bold).

```
html_theme = "sphinxdoc"
```

Output As below:

```
set_data(*, data)                          [source]

    Set the acquire task data.

    Return type: tuple[bool, str]   # This gets displayed in bold

    Args:
        data (Any): data.
    
    Returns:
        tuple[bool, str]: (True, msg) if successful, (False, msg) otherwise.

    Raises: None
```

As under `Returns:` It display the return type. So I want to remove this `Return type: tuple[bool, str]`  from the output. If that is not possible can we make it normal text by removing bold.

Is there any configuration setting for above?

Comment: Side question: qhy would you like to remove the types information ? Python il already very "bad" on that point, removing types from the documentation will likely confuse your users even more.

Comment: Hi Itération, Thanks. I want to remove `Return type: tuple[bool, str] ` As under `Returns:` it already display return type.